# Cleardb instance hosted in cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

What is the use of service key in cloud foundry ? Today i create one cleardb service and then pick the VCAP_SERVICES credentials . Then easily connect the cleardb through HeidiSQL tool with these credentials.

Also tried the same things through ssh without service key and its connect successfully .
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-services.html

Please let me know the importance of service key .

Regards
Mukul K

Answer (score 2):

Service keys allow you to get a set of (new) credentials for an app/use case outside of running CF apps. For example, you could get a new temporary ClearDB URI and pass it to mysqlsh on your laptop.

It is preferred to generate new creds for each use case/user rather than borrowing the creds from an app’s VCAP_SERVICE